# Two random variables are dependent given a third random variable, and independent otherwise

Tags: independence

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent given $Z$, and independent when not given $Z$. Does this mean that:

$$
p(x,y) = p(x) \cdot p(y) \\
p(x,y|z) \neq p(x|z) \cdot p(y|z)
$$

Also, are there any real-world examples of this scenario?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about examples of [Berkson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkson%27s_paradox).

Comment: Well, the formulas are just restating the hypotheses about X, Y, and Z.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There will be many examples of the form $Z = f(X, Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables and $f$ is some function.

For example, $X$ is the number I roll on a fair die, $Y$ is the number I roll on a second fair die, and $Z$ is $X + Y$.

Comment: How does this address the case where $X$ and $Y$ are dependent given $Z$?

Comment: In my example $X$ and $Y$ are dependent given $Z$. For example, $P(X=1,Y=2|Z=3) = 0.5 \ne 0.25 = P(X=1|Z=3)P(Y=2|Z=3)$.

Answer (score 5):

Yes the translation in formula is correct, up to a loose formalism.

A generic "real-world" example can be obtained when $X$ and $Y$ can
have either positive association or a negative association depending
on $Z$. Then $X$ and $Y$ may eventually be independent.

For instance $X$ be the income and $Y$ be the experience and $Z$ be a
type of professional activity. Then $X$ and $Y$ may be positively
associated for some values of $Z$ but negatively associated for some
others e.g. due to technical obsolescence. Examples can occur in
environmetrics when the relation between $X$ and $Y$ is subject to an
"inversion": $Z$ can be the time within day, day in year, rising/falling tide...

Note that this scenario can not happen when the joint distribution of
$X$, $Y$ and $Z$ is normal because the covariance of $X$ and $Y$
conditional on $Z = z$ does not depend on the value $z$. On the
contrary, easy examples are found with $Z$ being discrete or
multimodal.